# Tab-back with a custom component that wraps an input field

Tags: javascript, html, web-component, lit-element

Where I have a custom component that wraps an input element, I'm trying to ensure that `tabindex` is working correctly.

The following code will work for tabbing forward. But tabbing backwards (`Shift + Tab`) does not work correctly, it'll focus the outer wrapper `x-input` instead.

```
@customElement('x-input')
export class CustomInput extends LitElement {
  @query("input")
  private _input: HTMLInputElement;
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.tabIndex = this.tabIndex < 0 ? 0 : this.tabIndex;
    this.addEventListener("focusin", this._onFocusIn);
  }
  
  render() {
    return html`<input tabindex="-1">`;
  }
  
  private _onFocusIn(): void {
   this._input.focus();
  }
}
```

A full playgound/example can be found [here](https://lit.dev/playground/#project=W3sibmFtZSI6InNpbXBsZS1ncmVldGluZy50cyIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiJpbXBvcnQge2h0bWwsIGNzcywgTGl0RWxlbWVudH0gZnJvbSAnbGl0JztcbmltcG9ydCB7Y3VzdG9tRWxlbWVudCwgcXVlcnl9IGZyb20gJ2xpdC9kZWNvcmF0b3JzLmpzJztcblxuQGN1c3RvbUVsZW1lbnQoJ3gtaW5wdXQnKVxuZXhwb3J0IGNsYXNzIEN1c3RvbUlucHV0IGV4dGVuZHMgTGl0RWxlbWVudCB7XG4gIEBxdWVyeShcImlucHV0XCIpXG4gIHByaXZhdGUgX2lucHV0OiBIVE1MSW5wdXRFbGVtZW50O1xuICBcbiAgY29uc3RydWN0b3IoKSB7XG4gICAgc3VwZXIoKTtcbiAgICB0aGlzLnRhYkluZGV4ID0gdGhpcy50YWJJbmRleCA8IDAgPyAwIDogdGhpcy50YWJJbmRleDtcbiAgICB0aGlzLmFkZEV2ZW50TGlzdGVuZXIoXCJmb2N1c2luXCIsIHRoaXMuX29uRm9jdXNJbik7XG4gIH1cbiAgXG4gIHJlbmRlcigpIHtcbiAgICByZXR1cm4gaHRtbGA8aW5wdXQgdGFiaW5kZXg9XCItMVwiPmA7XG4gIH1cbiAgXG4gIHByaXZhdGUgX29uRm9jdXNJbigpOiB2b2lkIHtcbiAgIHRoaXMuX2lucHV0LmZvY3VzKCk7XG4gIH1cbn1cbiJ9LHsibmFtZSI6ImluZGV4Lmh0bWwiLCJjb250ZW50IjoiPCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw-XG48aGVhZD5cbiAgPHNjcmlwdCB0eXBlPVwibW9kdWxlXCIgc3JjPVwiLi9zaW1wbGUtZ3JlZXRpbmcuanNcIj48L3NjcmlwdD5cbjwvaGVhZD5cbjxib2R5PlxuICA8eC1pbnB1dD48L3gtaW5wdXQ-XG4gIDx4LWlucHV0IHRhYmluZGV4PVwiMVwiPjwveC1pbnB1dD5cbiAgPHgtaW5wdXQ-PC94LWlucHV0PlxuICA8eC1pbnB1dCB0YWJpbmRleD1cIjFcIj48L3gtaW5wdXQ-XG4gIDx4LWlucHV0PjwveC1pbnB1dD5cbjwvYm9keT5cbiJ9LHsibmFtZSI6InBhY2thZ2UuanNvbiIsImNvbnRlbnQiOiJ7XG4gIFwiZGVwZW5kZW5jaWVzXCI6IHtcbiAgICBcImxpdFwiOiBcIl4yLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwiQGxpdC9yZWFjdGl2ZS1lbGVtZW50XCI6IFwiXjEuMC4wXCIsXG4gICAgXCJsaXQtZWxlbWVudFwiOiBcIl4zLjAuMFwiLFxuICAgIFwibGl0LWh0bWxcIjogXCJeMi4wLjBcIlxuICB9XG59IiwiaGlkZGVuIjp0cnVlfV0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make use of `delegateFocus` property of the `shadowRoot`. It would work naturally. You don't need to setup complex `focus` event behavior:

```js
import {html, css, LitElement} from 'lit';
import {customElement, query} from 'lit/decorators.js';

@customElement('x-input')
export class CustomInput extends LitElement {
  static shadowRootOptions = {
    ...LitElement.shadowRootOptions,
    delegatesFocus: true
  };
  
  @query("input")
  private _input: HTMLInputElement;
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.tabIndex = this.tabIndex < 0 ? 0 : this.tabIndex;
  }
  
  render() {
    // The input element is naturally tabbable
    return html`<input tabindex="0">`;
  }
}
```

The `delegateFocus` will do two things:

- When the custom element is focused, the focus is given to the first focusable element inside the shadow root.
- When the inside element gets focused, the `:focus` style gets applied to your host/custom element. Read more about the [`delegateFocus` here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ShadowRoot/delegatesFocus). Also [this article](https://web.dev/shadowdom-v1/) has a nice explainer about handling focus.

Comment: Notice this this is still required `this.tabIndex = this.tabIndex < 0 ? 0 : this.tabIndex;`. Perhaps a separate question, but interested in how one should model disabled.